# Why is Informatica PowerCenter's lookup cache faster than a direct lookup to the source?

Tags: caching, lookup, lookup-tables, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Why is Informatica PowerCenter's lookup cache faster than a direct lookup to the source?

I understand it is faster, but why? Both direct lookup and the cached lookup queries an on disk table. I'd expect it to be cached in memory for it to be faster.

More information here: http://www.clearpeaks.com/blog/etl/boost-performance-of-informatica-lookups

> When a lookup is cached: Informatica queries the database, brings the whole set of rows to the Informatica server and stores in a cache file. When this lookup is called next time, Informatica uses the file cached. As a result, Informatica saves the time and the resources to hit the database again. - See more at: http://www.clearpeaks.com/blog/etl/boost-performance-of-informatica-lookups#sthash.fVWQ440D.dpuf

Why is it faster to use a cache file than the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In direct/uncached lookup, Informatica fires a select query on the database for each and every record. So if a million records are coming from source, it will hit the database a million times. This takes time on database end as well as to move the data over the network. Moving small chunks of data repeatedly over the network is costlier than sending it as a whole.

But in a cached lookup, Informatica fetches the whole set of records once and caches it in its **native** server. Also, the cache is **sorted** and **indexed** based on your condition columns. Now, when a lookup needs to performed, it just searches (there are very efficient searching algorithms available like **binary search**) the input fields in the cache, which is a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it up. We're working (i.e. learning) on computers with the source database on the same computer. It didn't occur to me that the server would be on a different machine over a network. Obvious now that I think about it. Again, thanks.